# How can i prevent explicit casting if you want to use properties of the sub-type?

Tags: java

So the compiler complains when ever i do a explicit cast. I can prevent this by using a @SuppressWarnings annotation. 
At this point i would have this annotation a lot in my code which lets me suspect that there is another way i'm just not aware of.

Lets have a look at this example

```
class CutePet
{
    public void pet()
    {
        System.out.println( "The cute pet gets some pets" );
    }
}

class Cat extends CutePet
{
    public void letOutside()
    {
        System.out.println( "The cat goes outside" );
    }


    public void letInside()
    {
        System.out.println( "The cat comes inside" );
    }


    public void removeTick()
    {
        System.out.println( "The cat looses all ticks" );
    }
}

class Dog extends CutePet
{
    public void goForAWalk()
    {
        System.out.println( "The Dog goes for a walk" );
    }


    public void tellHimWhatHeIs()
    {
        System.out.println( "The Dog is a good boy" );
    }
}

class caretaker
{
    public void takeCare( CutePet pet )
    {
        if( pet instanceof Cat )
        {
            pet.pet();
            ((Cat)pet).letOutside();
            ((Cat)pet).letInside();
            ((Cat)pet).removeTick();
        }
        else if( pet instanceof Dog )
        {
            pet.pet();
            ((Dog)pet).goForAWalk();
            ((Dog)pet).tellHimWhatHeIs();
        }
    }
}
```

The Caretaker does not know what kind of Pet he will get in advance and he my has several pets of different kinds.
I tried to give the Cute pet class a getType() method which returns a enum. With this enum i can remove the "instanceof" but the cast is still there.

Am i missing something?

Comment: What's the warning? Unchecked cast?

Comment: Which compiler? What is the exact and complete message?

Comment: But anyway, the way to avoid this is to make takeCare() an instance method of CutePet and override it in subclass, or to use the visitor pattern.

Comment: I don't really see any issue with what you are doing here so long as you are declaring pets as either cats or dogs and not as CutePets.

Comment: You didn't add constructors to Dog and Cat simply for brevity here, correct?

Comment: You should consider using an `interface`.  This type of construct is one of the reasons they are used.

Comment: @WJS would you explain how an interface is useful here? Maybe I am thinking about it in the wrong way but, having dog and cat implement caretaker methods seems odd.

Comment: You wouldn't get an unchecked cast warning in this code. All the casts are checked.

Comment: @brandonx  I provide you with an answer as well as an alternative.  Perhaps you can find something of use in one or the other to help with your code.

Answer (score 2):

If this were a real world problem, the caretaker would recognize which kind of pet he has based on the pet's appearance. While "instance of" is one way of looking at it, you might want to consider overloading the `takeCare` method directly with the subtypes as required. For example:

```
class Caretaker {
    public void takeCare(Cat pet) {
        pet.pet();
        pet.letOutside();
        pet.letInside();
        pet.removeTick();
    }

    public void takeCare(Dog pet) {
        pet.pet();
        pet.goForAWalk();
        pet.tellHimWhatHeIs();
    }
}
```

in other words, the caretaker knows what to do (has methods already in place) for the kind of pet he receives.

**EDIT**

In response to some of the comments, yes, the original example shifts the problem further up. If you have an array or a list of generic pets then you still have to figure out what kinds of pets you have to give them to the caretaker. Conceptually it seems strange that the pet should be able to pet itself, take itself for a walk, etc. (these methods are part of the pet class when it should be the caretaker doing these actions ON the pet).

I've since rewritten the code with a full working example below with a `Job` class that has a `perform` method. This method will return the appropriate job based on the type of animal the caretaker has. The caretaker can then perform the job on the pet in question. See below.

Doing things this way avoids `instanceof`. While it is debatable how good/bad instanceof actually is, where possible it should be the object itself to tell me what it needs, otherwise the whole polymorphism concept can get pretty hairy pretty quick.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Caretaker caretaker = new Caretaker();
        Arrays.asList(
                new Cat("Cat1"),
                new Cat("Cat2"),
                new Dog("Dog1")
        ).forEach(caretaker::takeCare);
    }

    interface CutePet {
        String whoAmI();
        Job whatINeed();
    }

    abstract static class NamedCutePet implements CutePet {
        private final String name;

        public NamedCutePet(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String whoAmI() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    static class Cat extends NamedCutePet {

        public Cat(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public Job whatINeed() {
            return new CatJob(this);
        }
    }

    static class Dog extends NamedCutePet {


        public Dog(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public Job whatINeed() {
            return new DogJob(this);
        }
    }

    static class Caretaker {

        void takeCare(CutePet pet) {
            pet.whatINeed().perform();
        }
    }

    static abstract class BaseJob implements Job {

        void pet(CutePet pet) {
            System.out.println(String.format("The cute pet %s gets some pets", pet.whoAmI()));
        }
    }

    static class DogJob extends BaseJob {

        private final Dog dog;

        public DogJob(Dog dog) {
            this.dog = dog;
        }

        @Override
        public void perform() {
            pet(dog);
            takeDogFarAWalk(dog);
            tellHimWhatHeIs(dog);
        }
        private void takeDogFarAWalk(Dog dog) {
            System.out.println(String.format("The dog %s goes for a walk", dog.whoAmI()));
        }

        private void tellHimWhatHeIs(Dog dog) {
            System.out.println(String.format("The dog %s is a good boy", dog.whoAmI()));
        }
    }

    static class CatJob extends BaseJob {

        private final Cat cat;

        public CatJob(Cat cat) {
            this.cat = cat;
        }

        @Override
        public void perform() {
            pet(cat);
            letOutside(cat);
            letInside(cat);
            removeTick(cat);
        }

        private void letOutside(Cat cat) {
            System.out.println(String.format("The cat %s goes outside", cat.whoAmI()));
        }

        private void letInside(Cat cat) {
            System.out.println(String.format("The cat %s comes inside", cat.whoAmI()));
        }

        private void removeTick(Cat cat) {
            System.out.println(String.format("The cat %s loses all ticks", cat.whoAmI()));
        }
    }

    interface Job {
        void perform();
    }

}
```

Comment: This just shifts the problem to another place. Lets say i have list list of pets List<CutePet> pets. I want to call takeCar() for each pet but there is no method signature with the signature takeCare(CutePet) i have to cast before hand.

Comment: Checking instanceof is also not an inherently bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make it clear: you can't call subclass specific methods without typecasting to subclass type.

Now, let me suggest an alternate way. Define a method `takeCare()` in the superclass and let the subclasses implement it by calling several specific methods specific to subclasses. Then from `CareTaker#takeCare()`, call only `takeCare()` method without typecasting.

Several other alternate approaches can be used to solve the situation.

Comment: While this works for simple cases, it fails as soon it becomes more complex. What if there are different Caretakers who do things in a different order? Also: why are the pets taking care of them self? Thanks tho. I may have to stick to casting

Comment: While I get where you are coming from @Saila, it may or may not be good practice to have objects operate on each other in such a way. There are multiple ways to go about this. Think about whether it is smart to have a centralized "CareTaker" class that seems to be a god object that performs many seemingly unrelated operations on the different animals. Again, there are multiple ways to do this and with such a trivial example, it's hard to know what is best.

Comment: Also, if the caretaker is taking care of the pets, he should be petting them, removing ticks, etc. As it is currently written, the pets are doing the work the caretaker should do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would do it with interfaces and reflection.  Note that only the interface methods are called for each pet type.  It could also be extended to call other methods.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class PetProblem {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Caretaker caretaker = new Caretaker();
      Dog dog = new Dog();
      caretaker.takeCare(dog);
      System.out.println("\nNow do it for the cat\n");
      Cat cat = new Cat();
      caretaker.takeCare(cat);
   }

}

interface CuteCat {
   void letOutside();
   void letInside();
   void removeTick();
}

interface CuteDog {
   void goForAWalk();
   void tellHimWhatHeIs();
}

interface CutePet {
   default void pet() {
      System.out.println("The cute pet gets some pets");
   }
}

class Cat implements CutePet, CuteCat {
   public void letOutside() {
      System.out.println("The cat goes outside");
   }

   public void letInside() {
      System.out.println("The cat comes inside");
   }

   public void removeTick() {
      System.out.println("The cat looses all ticks");
   }
}

class Dog implements CutePet, CuteDog {
   public void goForAWalk() {
      System.out.println("The Dog goes for a walk");
   }

   public void tellHimWhatHeIs() {
      System.out.println("The Dog is a good boy");
   }
}

class Caretaker {
   public void takeCare(Object pet) {
      Class<?>[] ifss = pet.getClass().getInterfaces();
      for (Class<?> ifs : ifss) {
         Method[] methods = ifs.getDeclaredMethods();
         for (Method m : methods) {
            try {
               m.invoke(pet);
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note however, that using interfaces and having a method so named that it can be used for all pets is easier.  Here is an example.  Since both dogs and cats need to eat, a common method `feedMe()` can be implemented for each.

```
public class AnimalShelter {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Caretaker caretaker = new Caretaker();
      Dog dog = new Dog();
      Cat cat = new Cat();
      caretaker.feedThePets(dog);
      caretaker.feedThePets(cat);
   }
}

interface SupperTime {
   void feedMe();
}

class Caretaker {
   public void feedThePets(SupperTime pet) {
      pet.feedMe();
   }
}

class Dog implements SupperTime {
   public void feedMe() {
      System.out.println("Oh boy, Kibbles n' Bits");
   }
}

class Cat implements SupperTime {
   public void feedMe() {
      System.out.println("Yum.  Purina Cat Chow");
   }
}
```